# Using collisions to control movements of objects in an animation

Tags: animation, physics

In the modeling of a mechanical assembly it is usually necessary to examine movements of mesh objects in relation to one another. In the simple example the green object would be animated to move along the X-axis and collision with the violet object would make it slide along its edge until it hits an obstacle. Can such control of movement be achieved in an animation using rigid body physics or object constraints?[image: Simple example of object collision in an animation]

Answer (score 0):

Yes - this is precisely what Rigid Body Physics is for.

Your objects will need to be 3-dimensional (your example image looks to only be 2D) and set up with Rigid Body on each. The green one you have have set as 'Passive' and 'Animated' in its settings (so that you can animate its position) and the violet one as 'Active'. You would need to setup a ground plane (also as 'Passive') for them to rest upon (or they will just fall under the influence of gravity) or add a Rigid Body Constraint to restrict its movement.

Running the simulation and moving the green object should result in the violet one responding and being pushed out of the way.

Comment: Old, inactive post so no big deal, but just FYI my interpretation was that OP wanted the leftward moving green object, upon contacting the violet one, to slide up the slope (i.e. at a 45 degree angle, left/up)..perhaps stopping when the vertical portion of the violet shape is hit. Still should work but I think violet can be Passive in that scenario. Or I could be totally wrong about all their intentions. ;)

Comment: Yeah, you’re possibly right. I never got any feedback from the OP and it’s ambiguous. Thanks for your comment though - always good to get another point of view.